# How to update single row in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, row, sql-update

I have 2 buttons, approve and reject to update booking status.
I am lost when trying to pass value to approve_booking.php.
Have no idea how to update single row according to bookingID. Need help on coding!!!

index.php

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myTable").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra']});
});

$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
} 
);

$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
} 
);
</script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="stylelogin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="approve_booking.php" >
<?php

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "eventdb");

$query = "SELECT customer.companyName, customer.contactName,eventinfo.eventTitle,boothAlias,date, testbook.bstatus, testbook.username, bookingID  from eventinfo, testbook, customer where testbook.username=customer.username AND testbook.eventID=eventinfo.eventID";

$result = $db->query($query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);

$o = '<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" width="660px"><thead><tr><th>Company Name</th><th>Contact Name</th><th>Event</th><th>Booth</th><th>Date</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

while(list($companyName, $contactName, $eventTitle, $boothAlias, $date, $bstatus,$bookingID) = $result->fetch_row()) {

if($bstatus==0){
    $status="Pending";
}else if($bstatus==1){
    $status="Successful";
}else{
    $status="Reject";
}


$o .= '<tr><td width="120px">'.$companyName.'</td><td width="120px">'.$contactName.'</td><td width="180px">'.$eventTitle.'</td><td width="70px">'.$boothAlias.'</td><td width="170px">'.$date.'</td><td width="70">'.$status.'</td><td width="100"><input width="100px" name="APPROVED" type="submit" id="APPROVED" value="Approve"> <input width="100px" name="REJECT" type="submit" id="REJECT" value="Reject"></td></tr>';
}

$o .= '</tbody></table>';

echo $o;
?>
</form>
</body>
```

approve_booking.php

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("eventdb") or die (mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['APPROVED']))
    {

        $query2 = "UPDATE testbook SET bstatus ='0' WHERE bookingID='$_POST[booking]'";
            $result2 = @mysql_query($query2);
    }


if (isset($_POST['REJECT']))
    {
        $query3 = "UPDATE testbook SET bstatus ='2' WHERE bookingID='$_POST[booking]'";
            $result3 = @mysql_query($query3);

    }



?>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KGLB.jpg

Comment: I think you are not passing your bookingID.. pass it using a hidden variable ...

Comment: NEVER EVER insert client data directly into sql statements. Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.
Client data must always treated as untrusted.
Use Prepared Statements instead: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If booking id is your auto increament / primary key so it update only single row but if its not then use your primary key in WHERE condition so it can find and update only 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i don't see any form fields in that form. 
create a hidden field with name of "booking"

```
  <input type="text" name="booking" value="<?php echo $bookingID; ?>" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you pass bookingID to php?

```
<input type="hidden" name="booking" id="booking">
```

add `onclick` function to both bottons to save selected row's bookingid to a hidden input.

```
onclick=$(\"#booking\").val('.$bookingID .');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably causing your problem.

```
snip
        $query3 = "UPDATE testbook SET bstatus ='2' WHERE bookingID='$_POST[booking]'";
/snip
```

Change it to this:

```
snip
        $query3 = "UPDATE testbook SET bstatus ='2' WHERE bookingID='{$_POST['booking']}'";
snip
```

Note that echoing post variables directly into query strings like these is highly unsecure. I suggest checking the variable first before putting it in there.

Anyway, your problem is the value of the variable `$_POST['booking']` probably wasn't passed into the query. It passed the string `$_POST['booking']`.